# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.servlet.Filter' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

**Eureka Server - Camden.SR2 - Spring Boot Starter 1.4.2.RELEASE**

I am getting the following error while trying to run Spring Boot Starter 1.4.2.RELEASE with Eureka server:

```
2016-11-21 22:33:53.420  INFO 20635 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2177849e: startup date [Mon Nov 21 22:33:53 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-11-21 22:33:53.836  INFO 20635 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-11-21 22:33:53.894  INFO 20635 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fc4b31a3] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)

2016-11-21 22:33:59.402  INFO 20635 --- [           main] i.v.p.s.EurekaServerApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-11-21 22:33:59.422  INFO 20635 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5c18016b: startup date [Mon Nov 21 22:33:59 CET 2016]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2177849e
2016-11-21 22:34:00.348  WARN 20635 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2016-11-21 22:34:00.655  INFO 20635 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=e1bdaab3-6fb3-3c45-9078-5ee488116098
2016-11-21 22:34:00.772  INFO 20635 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-11-21 22:34:00.936  INFO 20635 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fc4b31a3] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-11-21 22:34:01.378  INFO 20635 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8761 (http)
2016-11-21 22:34:01.397  INFO 20635 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-11-21 22:34:01.399  INFO 20635 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
2016-11-21 22:34:01.589  INFO 20635 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-11-21 22:34:01.590  INFO 20635 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2168 ms
2016-11-21 22:34:02.107 ERROR 20635 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter    : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'traceFilterRegistration' defined in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'traceFilterRegistration' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.servlet.Filter' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=webRequestLoggingFilter)}
2016-11-21 22:34:02.141  WARN 20635 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2016-11-21 22:34:02.315 ERROR 20635 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method traceFilterRegistration in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerConfiguration required a bean of type 'javax.servlet.Filter' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'resourceUrlEncodingFilter' in 'FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration.FreeMarkerWebConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnEnabledResourceChain did not find class org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator


Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'javax.servlet.Filter' in your configuration.
```

---

**pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.spring.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>EurekaServer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>EurekaServer</name>
    <description>Eureka discovery server example</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Camden.SR2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

**application.yml**:

```
server:
  port: 8761
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-server1
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

---

**Boot Application class**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

---

**NOTE**: if I set the `spring-boot-starter-parent` to the 1.4.1.RELEASE everything works.

---

This is my environment:

- MacOS Sierra 10.12.1
- Spring Tool Suite - Version: 3.8.2.RELEASE (Build Id: 201610040743 - Platform: Eclipse Neon.1 (4.6.1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opened an issue on GitHub: [#1491](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1491).

Solved by cleaning the maven repo: `rm -r $HOME/.m2`

Comment: This could be harmful, many people have complex settings.xml file within .m2 directory (like me) and other stuff (custom dependencies downloaded via vpn). Perfect solution would be a removal of specific jar. But which one?

Answer (score 8):

There should be a mismatch version between spring boot and spring cloud. If you use spring boot version 2.2.0.RELEASE you have to use spring cloud version Hoxton.RC1. If you use spring boot version 2.1.9.RELEASE, you have to use spring cloud version Greenwich.SR3.

Below is the sample:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by aligning my versions of spring-boot and spring-cloud, specifically **spring-boot-starter-parent** and **spring-cloud-dependencies**.

To see the latest compatible versions of these I used [SpringInitializr](https://start.spring.io/) to create a eureka server project and then looked at the generated pom.xml.

To create a eureka project from the link above:

- Select the spring boot version (I use the latest)
- Type 'eureka' into the Dependencies and select eureka-server

Click the 'Explore' button to view the generated pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

you can create this bean :

```
@Bean
public Filter webRequestLoggingFilter() {
    return new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I change the
<spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
to
<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve many issues like this coming with (Spring Boot + Spring Cloud) by matching versions of Spring Boot and Spring Cloud. Please refer this link for version matrix.
https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud